# Obfuscating/Hiding Information from other players when writing an AI for a game

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I'm making an AI for a card game in Python and was wondering how I can keep players' decision functions from accessing the information given to them by the game that they shouldn't be able to access (for example, other players' hands). Currently, the game object itself is being passed into the players' decision functions.

I can only see two avenues of improvement: to either carefully choose what you pass in (although even things like one's own deck shouldn't be able to be manipulated by oneself, sadly, so this might not work), or to somehow filter using some obfuscation method, but I can't really think of one. Can you think of a better way to design this?

Thanks!
Andrew

Comment: Please share the relevant code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Treat them like human players; don't give them the internal guts, just give them an interface to use.

E.g. give them an object that contains only the information they're allowed to access, and have the AI return a choice of which action they wish to perform.